# How to check if Django server has received POST request data

Tags: django, http, http-post

I'm sending my Django server POST requests via an external Python shell but am not sure if it is receiving the requests (I've had some trouble getting around the CSRF protection but believe I have dealt with that now.)  Is there maybe a log file I can check to see if the server received the data in the POST request?

Comment: Sure, you just set `print request.POST` at the beginning of your post view..

Comment: What server are you running? Is it local? If it's apache, you can check that the requests are being made in your apache logs. (same holds for any other server probably)